# How to visualize a graph with nodes divided in 2 clusters, edges should be present between the clusters and within the clusters , using python?

Tags: python, graph, cluster-computing, networkx, graphviz

I wanted to generate a graph that looks similar to this.

[image]

But For my code, I'm getting a graph like the one below

[image]

I have entered the following code by importing graphviz. I request somebody to help me make changes in it to get the required code.

```
from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph('G', filename='cluster.gv')
a=['1','2','3','4']
b=['5','6','7','8']

with g.subgraph(name='cluster_0') as c:
    c.attr(color='lightgrey')
    c.node_attr.update(style='filled', color='red')
    for i in a:
        c.node(str(i),shape='circle')
    c.attr(label='partition #1')

with g.subgraph(name='cluster_1') as c:
    c.attr(color='lightgrey')
    c.node_attr.update(style='filled', color='blue')
    for i in b:
        c.node(str(i),shape='circle')
    c.attr(label='partition #2')

g.edge('1','5')
g.edge('1','3')
g.edge('2','7')
g.edge('5','8')
g.view()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to make a reprex? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

- I don't use the Python api so I don't know if it will support my suggestion.
- 'Similar' is a very loose requirement.
- That said:
  Graphviz allows you to explicitly set the node positions (see here https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords).  If you want collections of ovals that combine to form an oval, you can do so.  Note that 'pos' values are in points while node sizes are in inches!

This program:

```
digraph ovaltest {
 graph [splines=line]

  node [color=red shape=box style=rounded height=.2 width=.2  ]
   p1_1 [pos="70,95" ]
   p1_2 [pos="120,95" ]
   p1_3 [pos="170,95" ]
   p1_4 [pos="220,95" ]
   p2_1 [pos="70,70" ]
   p2_4 [pos="220,70" ]
   p3_1 [pos="70,45" ]
   p3_4 [pos="220,45" ]
   p4_1 [pos="70,20" ]
   p4_2 [pos="120,20" ]
   p4_3 [pos="170,20" ]
   p4_4 [pos="220,20" ]
  node [color=blue shape=box style=rounded height=.2 width=.2  ]
   q1_1 [pos="350,95" ]
   q1_2 [pos="400,95" ]
   q1_3 [pos="450,95" ]
   q2_1 [pos="350,70" ]
   q2_3 [pos="450,70" ]
   q3_1 [pos="350,45" ]
   q3_3 [pos="450,45" ]
   q4_1 [pos="350,20" ]
   q4_2 [pos="400,20" ]
   q4_3 [pos="450,20" ]

  p2_1 -> p3_4 [dir="none"]
  p2_4 -> q1_2 [dir="none"]
  p2_4 -> q3_3 [dir="none"]
  p4_4 -> q4_1 [dir="none"]
}
```

And this command line:
**neato -n -Tpng yourfile.gv >yourfile.png**

produces this graph :

[image]